# How to add new country?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, countries

I am using [countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) and [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gems. There are some countries missing in the gems, or states of a country is it possible can we add new countries or states with custom data and use in our rails project.? What I need to do that?

Comment: Mark the answer that helped you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clone the gem repositories, make your changes and in your projects `Gemfile` refer to your own repositories for those gems. If you think your changes are useful for the community: make a pull request for the original project.

Comment: Thanks for reply yeah this makes sense. But can I test it locally?.

Comment: Yes, if you clone the repo you can test it locally. To test the gem in your main application, put this in your `Gemfile`: `gem 'countries', path: '../countries'`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the yaml file: https://github.com/hexorx/countries/blob/master/lib/cache/translations.yaml

> If you have made changes to YAML run rake clean_yaml prior to committing to ensure your YAML is formatted properly.